# How to remove specific JSON Key

Tags: jquery

I have got JSON Object as shown below

```
 var flds = {
  "EmpID": {
    "name": "EmpID",
    "type": "String",
    "hidden": false
    }
  "prefix": {
    "name": "prefix",
    "type": "String",
    "hidden": false
    }
  "createDate": {
    "name": "createDate",
    "type": "Date",
    "hidden": false
    }
  }
}
```

i am trying to remove createDate

i have tried as foloows

```
for (key in flds) {
        key = flds[key];
        if(key instanceof Object || flds.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(2<3)
            {
                if(key.name=='createDate')
                {
                     delete key;
                }
            }


        }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/67676/

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
delete flds.createDate;
```

Or

```
delete flds['createDate'];
```